# Unwanted Directory Redirection Laravel Site

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-5

I am building a site using a custom Laravel CMS.

In the public directory, there is a physical "resources" directory.

/home/fsk/cms/public/resources/

My site also has a page called resources.

http://fsk.mysite.com/resources

The problem is this resources page keeps redirecting to the resources physical directory. http://fsk.mysite.com/resources/ It keeps adding the trailing slash.

How do I stop this redirection? Here is my htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: It would be much much easier to rename the resources folder than try to hack around with your .htaccess. You could exclude that folder from the rewrite rules, but then requests for actual files inside it will fail.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the solution I wanted to hear. Is there any other work around?

Comment: No. How would your web server know the difference between a laravel route /resources and a file at /resources/file.ext? It wouldn't.

Comment: But aren't site.com/resources and site.com/resources/ different? Why does site.com/resources have to automatically redirect to site.com/resources/ ?

Comment: Because a URL without a file extension is a folder, and the only way to have clean URLs without file extensions is to route requests that aren't folders to index.php at the cost of not being able to use folder names in those routes.